# setting disk partition for user in active directory

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I’m looking to apply disk partition shared to an organizational unit in Active Directory,

so that said : any user connect with his account from any pc connected to domain, he will have his disk partition (z: for exemple)

but have no idea how to do it. ¿How can I do this?

P.S: I’m using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Are you looking to give each user his own personal share or do you want all users to have a connection to an already existing share?

Comment: each user his own personal share